# symbol mu with specific format

Tags: math-mode, formatting, symbols

[image: look at symbol in the first line]

look at symbol in the first line

as you seen that symbol I think it's mu symbol
how I can't show this symbol using latex

Comment: i think this is the symbol you mean: `The generating function $\mathcal{H}(x)$ ...`.  (and welcome to tex.sx.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is unclear to me which symbol you actually mean, here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The generating function $\mathcal{H}(x)$ in \ref{3.15.3} is a rational function whose poles all lie on the unit circle $|x|=1$. In fact, the poles are at various roots of unity.

What are multiplicities of poles? The point $x=1$ is a pole of multiplicity $M$, because the denominator of $\mathcal{H}(x)$ is divisible by $(1-x)^M$. Let $\omega=e^{2\pi ir/s}$ be a primitive (i.e., \emph{gcd}$(r,s)=1$) $s$th root of 1. What is the multiplicity with which this point $x=\omega$ occurs as a pole of $\mathcal{H}(x)$? It is equal to the number of $a_i$'s that are divisible by $s$. Since the $a_i$'s are relatively prime, it cannot be that \emph{all} of them are divisible by $s$.

Therefore $x=1$ \emph{is a pole of order} $M$ \emph{of} $\mathcal{H}(x)$\emph{, and every other pole has multiplicity} $<M$.

Suppose $\omega$ is a pole of order $r$. Then the portion of the partial fraction expansion of $\mathcal{H}$ that comes from $\omega$ if of the the form
\[ \frac{c_1}{(1-r/\omega)^r} + \frac{c_2}{(1-r/\omega)^{r-1}} + \ldots. \]
Now refer to the power series expansion \ref{2.5.7}, which we repeat here:
\[ \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum\limits_{n\geq0}\binom{n+k}{k}x^n. \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: this symbol $\mathcal{H} what I need

Comment: I want to kiss your head ^_^